# Apache Flink Watermark behaviour for TwoInputStreamOperator operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

There are 2 data streams with timestamp assigned and watermark generator defined as followed.

```
val streamA: DataStream[A] = kafkaStreamASourceOutput.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy
          .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[A](Duration.ofSeconds(0))
          .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[A] {
            override def extractTimestamp(element: A, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
              element.lastUpdatedMs
            }
          })
      )

val streamA: DataStream[B] = kafkaStreamBSourceOutput.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy
          .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[B](Duration.ofSeconds(0))
          .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[B] {
            override def extractTimestamp(element: B, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
              element.lastUpdatedMs
            }
          })
      )
```

When these 2 streams are connected in an operator then the minimum watermark from streamA or streamB acts as the watermark of connecting operator.

```
class CombineAB extends CoProcessFunction[A, B, C] {
   override def processElement1(elem: A, ctx:Context, out: Collector[C]) {
        out.collect(C(elem.x, elem.y, time.Now()))
   }
   override def processElement2(elem: B, ctx:Context, out: Collector[C]) {
        out.collect(C(elem.x, elem.y, time.Now()))
   }
}

val streamC: DataStream[C] = streamA.connect(streamB)
      .process(new CombineAB)
```

The watermark of `CombineAB` operator is the minimum of `A` or `B`. Based on that the elements of type `C` are marked late or not.

But since we have not attached any timestamp assigned to `C`, does that mean none of the elements from `CombineAB` operator are marked late? Hence windowing on C will not have any late records being dropped?

Let's say we attach a timestamp assigned and watermark generator to C as follows, then does it mean the watermarks from A and B are completely ignored and watermark of `CombineAB` depends only on timestamp field of C and the lateness defined with C.

```
     streamC.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        WatermarkStrategy
          .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[C](Duration.ofSeconds(0))
          .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[C] {
            override def extractTimestamp(element: C, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
              element.updatedTime
            }
          })
      )
```

Isn't there a way that I can attach the timestamp assigner to C and the watermark for `CombineAB` is still the minimum of `A` and `B` and elements of C are marked late based on C's assigned timestamp and wartermark of `CombineAB`

---

Update: Refined implementation of CombineAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

`forBoundedOutOfOrderness[A](Duration.ofSeconds(0))` is unusual. Any out-of-order events will be late. Why not use `forMonotonousTimestamps()`?

The records produced by `CombineAB` will have timestamps; there's no need to apply `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` to this stream. The timestamp of any records produced by the `Collector` is the timestamp of the incoming record.

If you do call `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` on stream C, the incoming watermarks will be filtered out, and you'll need to generate new watermarks.

Comment: CollectAB is producing elements of type C and we have not mentioned which field of C is to be used to extract its event timestamp. So which timestamp is Flink using as timestamp of C. Is it, when element of type A is processed and we collect an element of type C, then timestamp of element A is assigned to C. Similarly an element of type C collected as a result of incoming type B element, uses B's timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was trying to say.